# Click a button in code in Intraweb (VCL for the Web)

Tags: javascript, delphi, intraweb

Lets say I have an intraweb application (written in Delphi 2010) with an iwEdit (called iweLookup) and an iwButton (iwbSearch).  When enter is pressed in the iwEdit, I want the iwButton clicked.

The following code almost works, but I think I need something to re-render the page.

```
procedure TiwfLookupListing.iweLookupAsyncKeyDown(Sender: TObject;
  EventParams: TStringList);
begin
  if EventParams.Values['which'] = '13' then
  begin
    iwbSearchClick(Sender);
  end;
end;
```

However this requires a round trip to the server (which would be acceptable but not desirable).  Ideally I'd like a way of doing it in Javascript - presumably in the ScriptEvents for the iwedit (but my Javascript skills are currently, um, limited)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am not familiar with Delphi. Does your program get viewed on a web browser as HTML?

Comment: Yes, you can view the HTML.  Intraweb just generates an HTML page with a bunch of javascript to hook back into the Delphi side of things.

Comment: I've just test it and it works fine with IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pretty much solved this one, in the ScriptEvents for the button, for onKeyDown I used the following code:

```
if (event.which == 13) {
  IWBSEARCH_onclick(event);
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

But if there is a better way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

IWEdits have an OnSubmit event, you just need to bind the OnClick event of the button to this OnSubmit and the buttons OnClick will be executed when you press return, as long as the edit has focus.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30537187)